# PyQt: ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWebKitWidgets' - How to fix?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am attempting to create a PyQt5 application incorporating a `QWebView`. Oddly Qt Designer did not show the widget as a choice in the Widget Box pane but Qt Creator did (this may be relevant). After adding the widget to my form (and after testing that it worked) in Qt Creator I used `pyuic5` to convert to a Python script. However when I try to run it I get the error:

```
File "WebView Test.py", line 246, in <module>
from PyQt5 import QtWebKitWidgets
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWebKitWidgets'
```

All of the relevant PyQt5 packages that I can see are installed and no other widget causes any problems. I have tried searching the web but cannot find anyone with the same problem as me. I'm running Kubuntu 15.10. How can I fix this error?

Comment: There's probably separate packages for the pyqt webkit stuff on your platform.

Comment: @ekhumoro I've installed all the related ones I can find including libqt5webkit5, libqtwebkit-qmlwebkitplugin and libqt5webkit5-dev to no avail. I'm running Kubuntu 15.10, I'll add that to the OP.

Comment: Did you install `python-pyqt5` or `python3-pyqt5`? It's not enough to have just WebKit, you also need the PyQt bindings so that Python can use it.

Comment: What version of Qt are you using? I believe QtWebkit [got removed from Qt5.6](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.6).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I have python3-pyqt5 and all other standard PyQt packages installed, as I said in the OP no other widget causes any problems.

Comment: @Georg My Qt version is 5.4.2, and the widget functions in Qt Creator meaning it must be installed somewhere

Comment: @Biggles. As I said before, there are separate packages for the pyqt stuff. Do you have the [python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit) package installed?

Comment: @ekhumoro I did, however purging and reinstalling that package (to make absolutely sure) solved my issue! Thanks